# How does this step involving the Dirac delta work?

Tags: summation, dirac-delta

I'm learning the course of Digital Signal Processing and there is a formula what is not totally clear  to me.
$$
\begin{align*}
w[n]\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} \exp\left(-\frac{j2\pi kn}{M}\right)
&= w[n] \frac{1-\exp(-j2\pi n)}{1-\exp(-j2\pi n/M)} \\
&= w[n] 
\begin{cases}
M & \text{if } n = kM, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&= w[n] \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta[n-kM]
\end{align*}
$$
I don't understand how we go between the second and the third member. 
Please could somebody explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=kM$, then both the numerator and denominator are zero, implying you need to take a limit. Using l'Hopital's rule, you immediately get $M$. If $n$ is an integer and *not* a multiple of $M$, then only the numerator is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but I didn't understand why if n=kM the numerator is zero...in this case, I obtain $e^{-j2pikM}$ and it's not equal to one ...

Comment: @lauren: the term in the exponential is $-j 2\pi k M$, where $k M$ is an *integer*. Are you aware that $e^{-j2\pi }=1$?

Comment: OK I get it... Thanks a lot for your explaination.. it helped me a lot